# Darkflow directory doesn't show up in 'files' section in all the python notebooks in google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, yolo, darkflow

I installed Darkflow using the instructions in this link: https://www.datadiscuss.com/yolo-custom-model-part1/
On the left side of my GOOGLE COLAB notebook there are 3 dropdowns: table of content, codes snippets and files
the darkflow directory shows up in the files dropdown only in the notebook in which I installed Darkflow. When I open a new notebook, the darkflow directory is not there. What do I do to make this directory common to all notebooks?